# Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item without SDK version 23

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I built my app with version 23 but I had some issues with permissions. Now I want to come back to version 22 but I find this error:

```
/Users/m/AndroidStudioProjects/50-anys/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

This is my `gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.main"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/Vuforia.jar')

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0'
}
```

There is no 23 anywhere. Any idea?

Comment: after dependency changes, did you run 'clean' before the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because `com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0` also uses appcompat-v7.

Try replacing compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0' with this:

```
compile ('com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0'){
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Edit: Actually, com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0 uses

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

And your compile and target is 22, which may be your problem.

Comment: It worked but I had to write `compile ('com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0')`...

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem while trying to add the following library to my project: https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

I discovered that the library had this in its build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

The case was: My project's targetSdkVersion was 22 and the library I tried to use requires appcompat for sdk version 23.

Trying to fix it I discovered that Gradle doesn't let you use the 'appcompat-v7:23.1.1' if your targetSdkVersion or compileSdkVersion are not **23**.

**Solution:** To fix it I added the following to my compile statement:

```
compile ('com.github.alamkanak:android-week-view:1.2.6'){
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

**Note:** If you try this, you will see that it works. But be careful, since you are excluding a module from the library, you may run into many issues by doing this. **Pray to god that it doesn't happen.**